Relay LoginEvent to AWS EventBridge
I am trying to create a channel member for LoginEvent (/lightning/setup/EventManager/Login/view), but I failed to find the documentation to help me send the correct payload. The Salesforce Help article covers this for two of the event types (both of which I have used successfully in the past):

Change Data Capture
Custom Event

But is missing documentation for the third type (real time events). Through my trial error, I was able to understand that I do not need to create a channel for these and only need to create channel members (however this post challenges my assumption). But all my attempts have failed. Here is one of the payloads that I have tried.
POST: <domain>/services/data/v61.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember
Payload:
{
  "FullName": "LoginEventChannelMember",
  "Metadata": {
        "eventChannel": "LoginEvent",
        "selectedEntity": "LoginEventStream"
  }
}

Error received: 400 Bad Request
[
    {
        "message": "Unable to find the specified channel.",
        "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
        "fields": []
    }
]


I want to get real time LoginEvent logs per this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.real_time_event_monitoring_streaming.htm&type=5
Eventually I will be setting up Event Relay to EventBridge.

See doc for instructions

Thank you. That did the job.
